# Why isent background-image:url('bg.jpg'); working?

Tags: css, html, background-image

So I am working on a website and I'm trying to set the background of empty div with a set size and I can't figure out why it isn't working.  Anyone see something I don't? Thanks, Tim.

Code:

```
.headerbg{
width:100%;
background-image:url('bg.jpg');
height:500px;
margin-bottom:25px;
}




<div class="headerbg">

        </div>
```

Comment: Does the image exist?

Comment: Is the `bg.jpg` image in the same folder as your CSS file? In your network inspector, are you seeing a 404 error when the image is fetched?

Comment: Vlad, um.... Yes... Yes I am.

Comment: Thank you Vlad Magdalin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent such errors, you should define your urls relative to the document root. For instance, if your image is at http://example.com/path/to/image.jpg then you should use `url('/path/to/image.jpg')`. This removes any possible ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code, when I try it with a different image, it works fine:

```
background-image:url('http://placekitten.com/100/100');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/bWKBB/

So, the reason for the problem is that the browser can't find the image. There can be several reasons for that, like:

- The image doesn't exist
- The image exists in a different folder

If you have the CSS code in a `style` tag in the page, the URL for the image is relative to the location of the page. If you have the CSS code in a style sheet, the URL for the image is relative to the location of the style sheet file.